# Reducing dimensions using eigs or eig

Tags: matlab, pca

I have a 1024x704x256 image which I have reorganized into a 2D matrix.  Each row represents an energy channel and each column represents a pixel.  I am performing PCA to reduce the number of bands with the code:

```
A=A-repmat(mean(A,2),1,size(A,2));  
[V, D] = eig(cov(A'));  
Evalues = diag(D);  
pc = V * A;
```

where A=mean adjusted 2D data set, V=matrix of eigenvectors, and D=matrix of eigenvalues.

My problem is that the outputs (using either eigs or eig) for V and D are automatically in ascending order.  I have not had this issue using these functions before on smaller data sets.  I need to know which vector/value pairs correspond to the rows in matrix A for further analysis.  Any ideas?

Comment: The purpose of the PCA is to transform the original data to a set of orthogonal components. Thus, you *have* to loose the correspondence to rows in your original data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalue/eigenvector problem can be defined as

```
A*V = lambda*V
```

where `lambda` is scalar (an eigenvalue), and `V` is a vector (an eigenvector).

As far as I can see, nor the eigenvalues nor the eigenvectors have any specific correspondence to individual rows in the matrix `A`.

Can you elaborate on why you don't want your eigenvalues/vectors to be ordered?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I would like to reduce the number of variables from 256 to six or less.  When I reduce the number of variables, I am uncertain of which ones I will inevitably be keeping.  Perhaps this is not an issue of the eigs function, however I was confused with the ordered output, having received a non-ascending output before.

Comment: Hmmm...If memory serves, efficient eigenvalue/vector-finding algorithms return largest eigenvalue/vector pairs *first*, so it's entirely *unexpected* if the output of eig() would *not* be sorted...